# Click smiley and place in input field

Tags: javascript, html

How can I click on a smiley / emoji from a list and place it in a input field? I can see in the Inspect Element Q (console log) that it is being clicked but I can not find a way to copy it to the input field.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="bubble-container" ></div>           
</div>

<div class="emoji" onclick="javascript:smileySelect(event);">
    <span title="Happy Face">  </span>
    <span title="Grinning Face">  </span>
    <span title="Grinning Face with Smiling Eyes">  </span>
</div>          

<div id="sendCtrls">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your message here" id="text">
    <button id="myBtn" style="width: auto;"> Send </button>
    <span title="Emoji" onclick="javascript:smiliesSH();"> </span>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function smileySelect(event) {
// get selected item and place it in input field
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the clicked emoticon with `event.target` and add the textContent of that to the value of the input element.

I also added a check `event.target != event.currentTarget` to avoid all icons are inserted when you click on the parent but not on a child (emoticon). When your html content of the event handler gets more complicated then you probably want to add a class to all emoticon spans and check if the clicked element has that class.

```js
function smileySelect(event) {
  /*
  event.target = the actually clicked element
  event.currentTarget = the element that has the event handler
  
  When they are not equal we know the click was on a child of the .emoji element.
  Any child is valid since you only have the emoticon span elements inside the .emoji element.
  */
  if (event.target != event.currentTarget) {
    let smiley = event.target;
    document.querySelector('#text').value += smiley.textContent;
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="bubble-container"></div>
</div>

<div class="emoji" onclick="javascript:smileySelect(event);">
  <span title="Happy Face">  </span>
  <span title="Grinning Face">  </span>
  <span title="Grinning Face with Smiling Eyes">  </span>
</div>

<div id="sendCtrls">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Your message here" id="text">
  <button id="myBtn" style="width: auto;"> Send </button>
  <span title="Emoji" onclick="javascript:smiliesSH();"> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: this works perfectly, This was a script I kept coming back too week after week for several months because I just could not figure it out, I was being stubborn and wanted to try and do it for myself but I just could not do it. I tip my hat to you Sir! It is true, there is light at the end of the tunnel 

Comment: @CharlyWilly Glad i could help. I'd like to give the advise to not be shy to ask about problems you encounter. The important thing is to understand the answer that is given so you will learn from it and not blindly copy paste code.

Comment: I am looking at the code you written and I must admit, I was nowhere near with the code I was trying out. I would never have gotten this to work without your help. Javascript is not my usual programming language but I am battling my way though it slowly :)

Comment: @CharlyWilly It might look hard and complicated in the start, but once you got a solid base knowledge it will get a lot easier. Practice makes perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:-

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="bubble-container" ></div>           
</div>

<div class="emoji" onclick="smileySelect(event.target.innerHTML)">
    <span title="Happy Face">  </span>
    <span title="Grinning Face">  </span>
    <span title="Grinning Face with Smiling Eyes" >  </span>
</div>          

<div id="sendCtrls">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your message here" id="text">
    <button id="myBtn" style="width: auto;"> Send </button>
    <span title="Emoji" onclick="javascript:smiliesSH();"> </span>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function smileySelect(emoji) {
      if (emoji.includes("span") == false)
          document.getElementById("text").value += emoji;
};
```

Comment: @Charly Willy   Extremely sorry. It should be `.value` not `.innerHTML`.

Comment: that worked but I plan to add several hundred of smiles and adding  onclick="javascript:smiliesSH();"> to each line seems like a lot of text, something I was hoping to avoid. Having said that this is the only working code I have seen so far. thanks

Comment: Edited. Please have a look.